# if application re-open SharedPreferences not saving boolean

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have the following code in my project called `menu.class`

```
f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      
f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setClassName ("com.example.aplication", "com.example.application.levelone");
        startActivityForResult (intent, 0);              
    }             
}); 
}

public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
    f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

    switch (resultCode) {
        case 11: f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);               
    }                                  
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", true);

    if(levelTwoUnlocked){
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 

    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setClassName ("com.example.application", "com.example.application.leveltwo");
            startActivityForResult (intent, 0);              
        }             
    });     
}
```

The code is working fine. `f2` button is set visible and `f2lock` invisible.
But when I re-open the application the `f2` button back to visible.
Did my Preferences code not complete?

UPDATED

i had changed the preferences code like this

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = preferences.edit();
    boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("f2", true);
    ed.commit();
```

and when i re-open the application it still had the same problems

Comment: have you added the boolean value to your shared preferences, if yes then post the code snippet.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, we do not see the commit operation.

Comment: yes where is you edited SharedPreferences share that code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh can you show me how to put a commit(); operation in my code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the value of `f2`, but it doesn't look like you're saving it anywhere.

```
preferences.getBoolean("f2", true);
```

This will return the last saved value of `f2` or `true` if `f2` doesn't exist (i.e. you've never saved it in your SharedPreference instance) - it won't create or save any value in the SharedPreferences instance for you.

To save the value, you need to create a SharedPreferences editor, set the value (or values) you want to save and commit it:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("f2", levelTwoUnlocked);
editor.commit();
```

Now the next time you read the `f2` value, it will have whatever value you last committed.

Comment: @Chairizky have another look at my answer - you are calling `getBoolean` on your `preferences` object. You should be calling `putBoolean` on your `editor` instance.

Comment: so false is change to levelTwoUnlocked? it show error like this bro: levelTwoUnlocked cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You don't have to use `levelTwoUnlocked` - I just used that as an example. You can set the value to true, false or use any boolean variable you like.